# sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE statement not return yes

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

all time saatment not return no.

```
-(BOOL)updateProductTable:(NSString *)productid column_shop_Product_quantity:(NSString *) productquantity{
    NSLog(@"%@",productid);
    NSLog(@"%@",productquantity);

    const char *dbpath = [databasepath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ShopProduct set column_shop_Product_quantity=%@ WHERE column_shop_Product_id=%@",productquantity,productid];
        NSLog(@"%@",updateSQL);

        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_reset(statement);

                return YES;
            }   
            else {
                return NO;
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Never bind values to a query using `stringWithFormat:`.
2. You don't close the database in most cases.
3. You don't finalize the prepared statement in most cases.
4. You should add more error logging to determine the cause of any issues.
5. Why is the product quantity passed as a string instead of a number?
6. You should use `sqlite3_open_v2`.
7. Use local variables for the database and prepared statement.

Here is your code updated for all of these issues:

```
-(BOOL)updateProductTable:(NSString *)productid column_shop_Product_quantity:(NSString *)productquantity {
    NSLog(@"%@",productid);
    NSLog(@"%@",productquantity);

    BOOL res = NO;

    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    const char *dbpath = [databasepath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open_v2(dbpath, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *updateSQL = "UPDATE ShopProduct set column_shop_Product_quantity=? WHERE column_shop_Product_id=?";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, updateSQL, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 0, [productquantity intValue]);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [productid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                res = YES;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unable to update data: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open database at %@: %s", databasepath, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    return res;
}
```